# Cannot get Boost Spirit grammar to use known keys for std::map<>

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

I seem to be experiencing some mental block with Boost Spirit I just cannot get by. I have a fairly simple grammar I need to handle, where I would like to put the values into a struct, that contains a std::map<> as one of it's members. The key names for the pairs are known up front, so that only those are allowed. There could be one to many keys in the map, in any order with each key name validated via qi.

The grammar looks something like this, as an example.

```
test .|*|<hostname> add|modify|save ( key [value] key [value] ... ) ;

//
test . add ( a1 ex00
             a2 ex01
             a3 "ex02,ex03,ex04" );

//
test * modify ( m1 ex10
                m2 ex11
                m3 "ex12,ex13,ex14"
                m4 "abc def ghi" );


//
test 10.0.0.1 clear ( c1
                      c2
                      c3 );
```

In this example the keys for “add” being a1, a2 and a3, likewise for “modify” m1, m2, m3 and m4 and each must contain a value. For “clear” the keys of the map c1, c2 and c3 may not contain a value. Also, let's say for this example you can have up to 10 keys (a1 ... a11, m1 ... m11 and c1 ... c11) any combination of them could be used, in any order, for their corresponding action. Meaning that you cannot use the known key c*X* for the "add" or m*X* for "clear"

The structure follows this simple pattern

```
//
struct test
{
    std::string host;
    std::string action;
    std::map<std::string,std::string> option;
}
```

So from the above examples, I would expect to have the struct contain ...

```
// add ...
test.host = .
test.action = add
test.option[0].first = a1
test.option[0].second = ex00
test.option[1].first = a2
test.option[1].second = ex01
test.option[2].first = a3
test.option[2].second = ex02,ex03,ex04

// modify ...
test.host = *
test.action = modify
test.option[0].first = m1
test.option[0].second = ex10
test.option[1].first = m2
test.option[1].second = ex11
test.option[2].first = m3
test.option[2].second = ex12,ex13,ex14
test.option[2].first = m3
test.option[2].second = abc def ghi

// clear ...
test.host = *
test.action = 10.0.0.1
test.option[0].first = c1
test.option[0].second = 
test.option[1].first = c2
test.option[1].second = 
test.option[2].first = c3
test.option[2].second =
```

I can get each indivudal part working, standalone, but I cannot seem to them working together. For example I have the host and action working without the map<>.

I’ve adapted a previously posted example from [Sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe)  ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191531/cannot-get-boostspirit-parserlexer-working-for-token-types-other-than-stdst)) trying to get this to work (BTW: [Sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe) has some awesome examples, which I’ve been using as much as the documentation).

Here is an excerpt (obviously not working), but at least shows where I’m trying to go.

```
namespace ast {

    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    //
    using unused = qi::unused_type;

    //
    using string  = std::string;
    using strings = std::vector<string>;
    using list    = strings;
    using pair    = std::pair<string, string>;
    using map     = std::map<string, string>;

    //
    struct test
    {
        using preference = std::map<string,string>;

        string host;
        string action;
        preference option;
    };
}

//
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( ast::test,
                        ( std::string, host )
                        ( std::string, action ) )
                        ( ast::test::preference, option ) )

//
namespace grammar
{
    //
    template <typename It>
    struct parser
    {
        //
        struct skip : qi::grammar<It>
        {
            //
            skip() : skip::base_type( text )
            {
                using namespace qi;

                // handle all whitespace (" ", \t, ...)
                // along with comment lines/blocks
                //
                // comment blocks: /* ... */
                //                 // ...
                //                 -- ...
                //                 #  ...
                text = ascii::space
                    | ( "#"  >> *( char_ - eol )  >> ( eoi | eol ) ) // line comment
                    | ( "--" >> *( char_ - eol )  >> ( eoi | eol ) ) // ...
                    | ( "//" >> *( char_ - eol )  >> ( eoi | eol ) ) // ...
                    | ( "/*" >> *( char_ - "*/" ) >> "*/" );         // block comment

                //
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES( ( text ) )
            }

            //
            qi::rule<It> text;
        };
        //
        struct token
        {
            //
            token()
            {
                using namespace qi;

                // common
                string   = '"' >> *("\\" >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"';
                identity = char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *char_("a-zA-Z0-9_");
                real     = double_;
                integer  = int_;

                //
                value    = ( string | identity );

                // ip target
                any      = '*';
                local    = ( char_('.') | fqdn );
                fqdn     =  +char_("a-zA-Z0-9.\\-" );   // consession

                ipv4     =  +as_string[ octet[ _pass = ( _1 >= 0 && _1 <= 255 ) ] >> '.'
                        >>             octet[ _pass = ( _1 >= 0 && _1 <= 255 ) ] >> '.'
                        >>             octet[ _pass = ( _1 >= 0 && _1 <= 255 ) ] >> '.'
                        >>             octet[ _pass = ( _1 >= 0 && _1 <= 255 ) ] ];

                //
                target   = ( any | local | fqdn | ipv4 );

                //
                pair     =  identity >> -( attr( ' ' ) >> value );
                map      =  pair >> *( attr( ' ' ) >> pair );
                list     =  *( value );

                //
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES( ( string )
                                        ( identity )
                                        ( value )
                                        ( real )
                                        ( integer )
                                        ( any )
                                        ( local )
                                        ( fqdn )
                                        ( ipv4 )
                                        ( target )
                                        ( pair )
                                        ( keyval )
                                        ( map )
                                        ( list ) )
            }

            //
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> string;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> identity;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> value;
            qi::rule<It, double()>      real;
            qi::rule<It, int()>         integer;
            qi::uint_parser<unsigned, 10, 1, 3> octet;

            qi::rule<It, std::string()> any;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> local;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> fqdn;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> ipv4;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> target;

            //
            qi::rule<It, ast::map()>  map;
            qi::rule<It, ast::pair()> pair;
            qi::rule<It, ast::pair()> keyval;
            qi::rule<It, ast::list()> list;
        };

    //
        struct test : token, qi::grammar<It, ast::test(), skip>
        {
            //
            test() : test::base_type( command_ )
            {
                using namespace qi;
                using namespace qr;

                auto kw = qr::distinct( copy( char_( "a-zA-Z0-9_" ) ) );

                // not sure how to enforce the "key" names!
                key_     = *( '(' >> *value >> ')' );
                // tried using token::map ... didn't work ...

                //
                add_     = ( ( "add"    >> attr( ' ' ) ) [ _val = "add" ] );
                modify_  = ( ( "modify" >> attr( ' ' ) ) [ _val = "modify" ] );
                clear_   = ( ( "clear"  >> attr( ' ' ) ) [ _val = "clear" ] );

                //
                action_  = ( add_ | modify_ | clear_ );


                /* *** can't get from A to B here ... not sure what to do *** */

                //
                command_ =  kw[ "test" ]
                        >> target
                        >> action_
                        >> ';';

                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES( ( command_ )
                                        ( action_ )
                                        ( add_ )
                                        ( modify_ )
                                        ( clear_ ) )
            }

            //
            private:
                //
                using token::value;
                using token::target;
                using token::map;

                qi::rule<It, ast::test(), skip> command_;
                qi::rule<It, std::string(), skip> action_;

                //
                qi::rule<It, std::string(), skip> add_;
                qi::rule<It, std::string(), skip> modify_;
                qi::rule<It, std::string(), skip> clear_;
        };

    ...

    };
}
```

I hope this question isn't too ambiguous and if you need a working example of the problem, I can certainly provide that. Any and all help is greatly appreciated, so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes:

1. with this

   ```
           add_     = ( ( "add"    >> attr( ' ' ) ) [ _val = "add" ] );
           modify_  = ( ( "modify" >> attr( ' ' ) ) [ _val = "modify" ] );
           clear_   = ( ( "clear"  >> attr( ' ' ) ) [ _val = "clear" ] );
   ```

   did you mean to require a space? Or are you really just trying to force the struct `action` field to contain a trailing space (that's what will happen).

   If you meant the latter, I'd do that outside of the parser¹.

   If you wanted the first, use the `kw` facility:

   ```
           add_    = kw["add"]    [ _val = "add"    ];
           modify_ = kw["modify"] [ _val = "modify" ];
           clear_  = kw["clear"]  [ _val = "clear"  ];
   ```

   In fact, you can simplify that (again, ¹):

   ```
           add_    = raw[ kw["add"] ];
           modify_ = raw[ kw["modify"] ];
           clear_  = raw[ kw["clear"] ];
   ```

   Which also means that you can simplify to

   ```
           action_  = raw[ kw[lit("add")|"modify"|"clear"] ];
   ```

   However, getting a bit close to your question, you could also use a [symbol parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/string/symbols.html):

   ```
           symbols<char> action_sym;
           action_sym += "add", "modify", "clear";
           //
           action_  = raw[ kw[action_sym] ];
   ```

   > Caveat: the symbols needs to be a member so its lifetime extends beyond the constructor.
2. If you meant to capture the input representation of ipv4 addresses with

   ```
           ipv4     =  +as_string[ octet[ _pass = ( _1 >= 0 && _1 <= 255 ) ] >> '.'
               >>             octet[ _pass = ( _1 >= 0 && _1 <= 255 ) ] >> '.'
               >>             octet[ _pass = ( _1 >= 0 && _1 <= 255 ) ] >> '.'
               >>             octet[ _pass = ( _1 >= 0 && _1 <= 255 ) ] ];
   ```

   > **Side note** I'm assuming `+as_string` is a simple mistake and you meant `as_string` instead.

   Simplify:

   ```
       qi::uint_parser<uint8_t, 10, 1, 3> octet;
   ```

   This obviates the range checks (see ¹ again):

   ```
       ipv4 = as_string[ octet >> '.' >> octet >> '.' >> octet >> '.' >> octet ];
   ```

   However, this would build a 4-char binary string representation of the address. If you wanted that, fine. I doubt it (because you'd have written `std::array<uint8_t, 4>` or `uint64_t`, right?). So if you wanted the string, again use `raw[]`:

   ```
       ipv4     = raw[ octet >> '.' >> octet >> '.' >> octet >> '.' >> octet ];
   ```
3. Same issue as with number 1.:

   ```
       pair     =  identity >> -( attr(' ') >> value );
   ```

   This time, the problem betrays that the productions should not be in `token`; Conceptually `token`-izing precedes parsing and hence I'd keep the tokens skipper-less. `kw` doesn't really do a lot of good in that context. Instead, I'd move `pair`, `map` and `list` (unused?) into the parser:

   ```
       pair     =  kw[identity] >> -value;
       map      =  +pair;
       list     =  *value;
   ```

### Some examples

There's a very recent example I made about using `symbols` to parse ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127867/boost-string-matching-dfa/48133103#48133103)), but this answer comes a lot closer to your question:

- [How to provider user with autocomplete suggestions for given boost::spirit grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354226/how-to-provider-user-with-autocomplete-suggestions-for-given-boostspirit-gramm/47383910#47383910)

It goes *far* beyond the scope of your parser because it does all kinds of actions in the grammar, but what it *does* show is to have generic "lookup-ish" rules that can be parameterized with a particular "symbol set": see the [**Identifier Lookup** section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354226/how-to-provider-user-with-autocomplete-suggestions-for-given-boostspirit-gramm/47383910#47383910) of the answer:

> #### Identifier Lookup
>
> We store "symbol tables" in `Domain` members `_variables` and
>   `_functions`:
>
> ```
>       using Domain = qi::symbols<char>;           Domain _variables, _functions;
> ```
>
> Then we declare some rules that can do lookups on either of them:
>
> ```
>       // domain identifier lookups
>       qi::_r1_type _domain;
>       qi::rule<It, Ast::Identifier(Domain const&)> maybe_known, known,
> ```
>
> unknown;
>
> The corresponding declarations will be shown shortly.
>
> Variables are pretty simple:
>
> ```
>       variable   = maybe_known(phx::ref(_variables));
> ```
>
> Calls are trickier. If a name is unknown we don't want to assume it
>   implies a *function* unless it's followed by a `'('` character.
>   However, if an identifier is a known function name, we want even to
>   imply the `(` (this gives the UX the appearance of autocompletion
>   where when the user types `sqrt`, it suggests the next character to be
>   `(` magically).
>
> ```
>       // The heuristics:          // - an unknown identifier followed by (
>       // - an unclosed argument list implies )            call %= (
> ```
>
> known(phx::ref(_functions)) // known -> imply the parens
>                          | &(identifier >> '(') >> unknown(phx::ref(_functions))
>                          ) >> implied('(') >> -(expression % ',') >> implied(')');
>
> It all builds on `known`, `unknown` and `maybe_known`:
>
> ```
>           ///////////////////////////////
>           // identifier loopkup, suggesting
>           {
>               maybe_known = known(_domain) | unknown(_domain);
>
>               // distinct to avoid partially-matching identifiers
>               using boost::spirit::repository::qi::distinct;
>               auto kw     = distinct(copy(alnum | '_'));
>
>               known       = raw[kw[lazy(_domain)]];
>               unknown     = raw[identifier[_val=_1]] [suggest_for(_1, _domain)];
>           }
> ```

I think you can use the same approach constructively here. One additional gimmick could be to validate that properties supplied are, in fact, unique.

### Demo Work

Combining all the hints above makes it compile and "parse" the test commands:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3db1cd75828e7aae)</kbd>**

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

namespace ast {

    //
    using string  = std::string;
    using strings = std::vector<string>;
    using list    = strings;
    using pair    = std::pair<string, string>;
    using map     = std::map<string, string>;

    //
    struct command {
        string host;
        string action;
        map option;
    };
}

#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::command, host, action, option)

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_distinct.hpp>

namespace grammar
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace qr = boost::spirit::repository::qi;

    template <typename It>
    struct parser
    {
        struct skip : qi::grammar<It> {

            skip() : skip::base_type(text) {
                using namespace qi;

                // handle all whitespace along with line/block comments
                text = ascii::space
                    | (lit("#")|"--"|"//") >> *(char_ - eol)  >> (eoi | eol) // line comment
                    | "/*" >> *(char_ - "*/") >> "*/";         // block comment

                //
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((text))
            }

          private:
            qi::rule<It> text;
        };
        //
        struct token {
            //
            token() {
                using namespace qi;

                // common
                string   = '"' >> *("\\" >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"';
                identity = char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *char_("a-zA-Z0-9_");
                value    = string | identity;

                // ip target
                any      = '*';
                local    = '.' | fqdn;
                fqdn     = +char_("a-zA-Z0-9.\\-"); // concession

                ipv4     = raw [ octet >> '.' >> octet >> '.' >> octet >> '.' >> octet ];
                //
                target   = any | local | fqdn | ipv4;

                //
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                        (string) (identity) (value)
                        (any) (local) (fqdn) (ipv4) (target)
                   )
            }

          protected:
            //
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> string;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> identity;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> value;
            qi::uint_parser<uint8_t, 10, 1, 3> octet;

            qi::rule<It, std::string()> any;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> local;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> fqdn;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> ipv4;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> target;
        };

        //
        struct test : token, qi::grammar<It, ast::command(), skip> {
            //
            test() : test::base_type(command_)
            {
                using namespace qi;

                auto kw = qr::distinct( copy( char_( "a-zA-Z0-9_" ) ) );

                //
                action_sym += "add", "modify", "clear";
                action_  = raw[ kw[action_sym] ];

                //
                command_ =  kw["test"]
                        >> target
                        >> action_
                        >> '(' >> map >> ')'
                        >> ';';

                //
                pair     = kw[identity] >> -value;
                map      = +pair;
                list     = *value;

                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                        (command_) (action_)
                        (pair) (map) (list)
                    )
            }

          private:
            using token::target;
            using token::identity;
            using token::value;
            qi::symbols<char> action_sym;

            //
            qi::rule<It, ast::command(), skip> command_;
            qi::rule<It, std::string(), skip> action_;

            //
            qi::rule<It, ast::map(), skip>  map;
            qi::rule<It, ast::pair(), skip> pair;
            qi::rule<It, ast::list(), skip> list;
        };

    };
}

#include <fstream>

int main() {
    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    using Parser = grammar::parser<It>;

    std::ifstream input("input.txt");
    It f(input >> std::noskipws), l;

    Parser::skip const s{};
    Parser::test const p{};

    std::vector<ast::command> data;
    bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l, *p, s, data);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << data.size() << " commands\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parsed failed\n";
    }

    if (f != l) {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed 3 commands
```

### Let's restrict the Keys

Like in the linked answer above, let's pass the `map`, `pair` rules the actual key set to get their allowed values from:

```
    using KeySet = qi::symbols<char>;
    using KeyRef  = KeySet const*;
    //
    KeySet add_keys, modify_keys, clear_keys;
    qi::symbols<char, KeyRef> action_sym;

    qi::rule<It, ast::pair(KeyRef),   skip> pair;
    qi::rule<It, ast::map(KeyRef),    skip> map;
```

> **Note** A key feature used is the associated attribute value with a `symbols<>` lookup (in this case we associate a `KeyRef` with an action symbol):

```
    //
    add_keys    += "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6";
    modify_keys += "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4";
    clear_keys  += "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5";

    action_sym.add
      ("add", &add_keys)
      ("modify", &modify_keys)
      ("clear", &clear_keys);
```

Now the heavy lifting starts.

#### Using `qi::locals<>` and *inherited attributes*

Let's give `command_` some local space to store the selected keyset:

```
  qi::rule<It, ast::command(), skip, qi::locals<KeyRef> > command_;
```

Now we can in principle assignt to it (using the `_a` placeholder). However, there's some details:

```
    //
    qi::_a_type selected;
```

Always prefer descriptive names :) `_a` and `_r1` get old pretty quick. Things are confusing enough as it is.

```
    command_ %= kw["test"]
            >> target
            >> raw[ kw[action_sym] [ selected = _1 ] ]
            >> '(' >> map(selected) >> ')'
            >> ';';
```

> **Note**: the subtlest detail here is `%=` instead of `=` to avoid the suppression of automatic attribute propagation when a semantic action is present (yeah, see ¹ again...)

But all in all, that doesn't read so bad?

```
    //
    qi::_r1_type symref;
    pair     = raw[ kw[lazy(*symref)] ] >> -value;
    map      = +pair(symref);
```

And now at least things parse

### Almost there

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38c620babc180d71)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

namespace ast {

    //
    using string  = std::string;
    using strings = std::vector<string>;
    using list    = strings;
    using pair    = std::pair<string, string>;
    using map     = std::map<string, string>;

    //
    struct command {
        string host;
        string action;
        map option;
    };
}

#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::command, host, action, option)

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_distinct.hpp>

namespace grammar
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace qr = boost::spirit::repository::qi;

    template <typename It>
    struct parser
    {
        struct skip : qi::grammar<It> {

            skip() : skip::base_type(rule_) {
                using namespace qi;

                // handle all whitespace along with line/block comments
                rule_ = ascii::space
                    | (lit("#")|"--"|"//") >> *(char_ - eol)  >> (eoi | eol) // line comment
                    | "/*" >> *(char_ - "*/") >> "*/";         // block comment

                //
                //BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((skipper))
            }

          private:
            qi::rule<It> rule_;
        };
        //
        struct token {
            //
            token() {
                using namespace qi;

                // common
                string   = '"' >> *("\\" >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"';
                identity = char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *char_("a-zA-Z0-9_");
                value    = string | identity;

                // ip target
                any      = '*';
                local    = '.' | fqdn;
                fqdn     = +char_("a-zA-Z0-9.\\-"); // concession

                ipv4     = raw [ octet >> '.' >> octet >> '.' >> octet >> '.' >> octet ];
                //
                target   = any | local | fqdn | ipv4;

                //
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                        (string) (identity) (value)
                        (any) (local) (fqdn) (ipv4) (target)
                   )
            }

          protected:
            //
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> string;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> identity;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> value;
            qi::uint_parser<uint8_t, 10, 1, 3> octet;

            qi::rule<It, std::string()> any;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> local;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> fqdn;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> ipv4;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> target;
        };

        //
        struct test : token, qi::grammar<It, ast::command(), skip> {
            //
            test() : test::base_type(start_)
            {
                using namespace qi;

                auto kw = qr::distinct( copy( char_( "a-zA-Z0-9_" ) ) );

                //
                add_keys    += "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6";
                modify_keys += "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4";
                clear_keys  += "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5";

                action_sym.add
                  ("add", &add_keys)
                  ("modify", &modify_keys)
                  ("clear", &clear_keys);

                //
                qi::_a_type selected;

                command_ %= kw["test"]
                        >> target
                        >> raw[ kw[action_sym] [ selected = _1 ] ]
                        >> '(' >> map(selected) >> ')'
                        >> ';';

                //
                qi::_r1_type symref;
                pair     = raw[ kw[lazy(*symref)] ] >> -value;
                map      = +pair(symref);
                list     = *value;

                start_   = command_;

                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                        (start_) (command_)
                        (pair) (map) (list)
                    )
            }

          private:
            using token::target;
            using token::identity;
            using token::value;

            using KeySet = qi::symbols<char>;
            using KeyRef  = KeySet const*;

            //
            qi::rule<It, ast::command(), skip> start_;
            qi::rule<It, ast::command(), skip, qi::locals<KeyRef> > command_;

            //
            KeySet add_keys, modify_keys, clear_keys;
            qi::symbols<char, KeyRef> action_sym;

            qi::rule<It, ast::pair(KeyRef),   skip> pair;
            qi::rule<It, ast::map(KeyRef),    skip> map;
            qi::rule<It, ast::list(),         skip> list;
        };

    };
}

#include <fstream>

int main() {
    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    using Parser = grammar::parser<It>;

    std::ifstream input("input.txt");
    It f(input >> std::noskipws), l;

    Parser::skip const s{};
    Parser::test const p{};

    std::vector<ast::command> data;
    bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l, *p, s, data);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << data.size() << " commands\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parsed failed\n";
    }

    if (f != l) {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed 3 commands
```

### HOLD ON, NOT SO FAST! It's wrong

Yeah. If you enable debug, you'll see it parses things oddly:

```
 <attributes>[[[1, 0, ., 0, ., 0, ., 1], [c, l, e, a, r], [[[c, 1], [c, 2]], [[c, 3], []]]]]</attributes>
```

This is actually "merely" a problem with the grammar. If the grammar cannot see the difference between a `key` and `value` then obviously `c2` is going to be parsed as the *value* of property with key `c1`.

It's up to you to disambiguate the grammar. For now, I'm going to demonstrate a fix using a *negative assertion*: we only accept values that are not *known keys*. It's a bit dirty, but might be useful to you for instructional purposes:

```
    key      = raw[ kw[lazy(*symref)] ];
    pair     = key(symref) >> -(!key(symref) >> value);
    map      = +pair(symref);
```

Note I factored out the `key` rule for readability:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/771f09382109b4ac)</kbd>**

Parses

```
<attributes>[[[1, 0, ., 0, ., 0, ., 1], [c, l, e, a, r], [[[c, 1], []], [[c, 2], []], [[c, 3], []]]]]</attributes>
```

Just what the doctor ordered!

---

¹ [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Comment: I saw that post, but didn't correlate that example with my issue (I'll look again). Why is only the first literal wrapped in lit() for ```action_  = raw[ kw[lit("add")|"modify"|"clear"] ];```. After reviewing, I may have follow up questions (I just can't seem to get my head around Spirit).

Comment: You could wrap all the literals, but operator overloading takes care of that. The first one requires the hint so we find the Spirit Qi domain operator overloads.

Comment: I just added a [working live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3db1cd75828e7aae) that incorporates the added notes (1. - 3.)

Comment: [Added two overkill chapters for good measure](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48178358/revisions). The final live demo is [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/771f09382109b4ac). What you don't see is that omitted values are now "sensibly" parsed :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162854/discussion-between-sehe-and-nvanwyen).